# Nodejs Rewrite HTTP Request Post body

Tags: node.js, http, post, proxy, header

I have setup a nodejs proxy with node-http-proxy. I have a client sending out REST API calls with http-post. I would like to add/modify some fields in the request post body.

How can I do this? Can I change the content length in the header and then change the post body directly, and then send out?